# Splitting string based on variable number of white spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need to split a string that looks like this

```
1052 root         0 SW<  [hwevent]
```

into the following

```
1052
root
0
SW<
[hwevent]
```

sure, I could just whip up a forloop and compare character indices with white spaces and when the occurrence is not a white space, add the occurrence to a new string array but I feel like this is  a really dirty way to do this.

What is a good way to split this string? Regex perhaps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may use [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptryEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
string strtemp = "1052 root         0 SW<  [hwevent]";
string[] array = strtemp.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, regex:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\s+");
```

**Explanation:**

`\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters at once, so it splits on any (positive) number of whitespace characters.